# How do Big Lizzie Romance Points gained from death work with Unkillable?

Tags: published-adventures, character-death, gurps-4e

In GURPS Big Lizzie there is a mechanic called romance points and dying gets you 50 romance points. But what happens if the person who has died has the Unkillable 2 or Unkillable 3 advantage? Would that reduce the number of points gained as there is no sacrifice that has been made?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the actual effect of the Romance points (second column, p5 of ***GURPS Big Lizzie***), they only affect the order in which the characters get to attempt to win Donna Nesbitt's heart after the adventure. The GM may award bonuses or penalties to each character's attempt, but this is optional.

The adventure is intended for about eight 150-point characters, and specifies that the PCs should have few, if any, extranormal powers. If I were running it, I wouldn't allow Unkillable, which is wildly extranormal. If it was allowed, Unkillable 2 costs 100 points, and Unkillable 3 costs 150 points, which is really going to limit what a 150-point character with either advantage can do.

With all those caveats, if a character had one of those advantages, I'd award Romance Points as if they'd been wounded (20 RP), since being wounded is the worst thing that injuries can do to them. I'd warn the player of this when they made their character, of course.